# Docker pull fails behind Apache

Tags: apache, docker, proxy

I have a custom Docker registry, accessible through http://localhost:5000

Here is the Apache config:

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName registry.mycompany.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    ...
    SSLCertificateKeyFile ...
    SSLCACertificateFile  /etc/pki/tls/certs/thawte.pem

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass         / http://localhost:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse  / http://localhost:5000/
    ProxyRequests     Off
</VirtualHost>
```

And here how I start the registry:

```
docker run -d \
    -p 5000:5000 \
    -e REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true \
    -e REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd \
    -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM="Registro" \
    -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd \
    --restart=always \
    --name registro \
    registry:2
```

Everything works ok (docker pull, ...), but `docker push` fails.  After some retrying here is the error message shown:

```
first path segment in URL cannot contain colon
```

Related doc can be found here:

- https://www.devco.net/archives/2015/01/21/running-a-secure-docker-registry-behind-apache.php

Comment: did you try to change localhost with 127.0.0.1 on your apache config?

Comment: What push command are you using exactly? Did you try without the proxy (to test) ?

Comment: Please use this file and see if it works for you https://github.com/azurecr-test/distribution-uaenorth/blob/fa88f6b68d28f596684c45538422b524080db1f9/contrib/apache/apache.conf

Comment: Thanks @cagta, but changing localhost for 127.0.0.1 provides no changes.

Comment: @PierreB.the command that fails is `docker push registry.mycompany.com/myimage:mytag`

Comment: @PierreB., that's right!

Comment: @TarunLalwani, I've tried to adapt your valuable example but it keeps failing. :-(

Comment: try: `docker push registry.mycompany.com:443/myimage:myta`

Comment: Which version of Docker are you using?

Comment: `Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b`

Comment: @ofirule, I've tried to use `registry.mycompany.com:443/myimage:mytag`, and it doesn't work either.  :-(

Comment: Maybe, I'll try nginx or some other alternative to Apache.

Comment: Try to use quotes in your Apache config: `ProxyPass        "/" "http://localhost:5000/"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With docker compose, I use the image `jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine` as a proxy, and it works much better

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  registry:
    image: registry:2
    expose:
    - 5000
    volumes:
    - "./registry.yaml:/etc/docker/registry/config.yml"
    - "./img:/var/lib/registry"
    - "./certs:/certs"
    - "./auth:/auth"
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: registry.company.com
    restart: always
  gui:
    image: joxit/docker-registry-ui:static
    environment:
      URL: https://registry.company.com
      REGISTRY_TITLE: Company Docker registry
      DELETE_IMAGES: "true"
      VIRTUAL_HOST: gui-registry.company.com
      #HTTPS_METHOD: nohttps
    expose:
    - 80
  proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
    - "/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro"
    - "./certs:/etc/nginx/certs"
    - "./registry.conf:/etc/nginx/vhost.d/registro.fccma.com"
    - "./cors.conf:/etc/nginx/vhost.d/registro.fccma.com_location"
    environment:
      DEFAULT_HOST: registro.fccma.com
```

In this way, I can have the Docker registry and its corresponding GUI in the same host.